# Laravel, Local Hosted cURL error 60: SSL certificate

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, curl, guzzle

I keep getting the error which calling an API locally, works fine on my server:

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate

Is there a way to stop this exception from showing locally?

Here's my code, ignore the () as this is variable info:

```
public function testCheck($domains){

        $client = new Client();

        $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.namecheap.com/xml.response?ApiUser=(username)&ApiKey=(apikey)&UserName(username)&ClientIp=(ip)&Command=namecheap.domains.check&DomainList=' . $domains);

        $data = json_decode($res->getBody());

        dd($data);

    }
```

Is there a way to stop this exception from showing locally so I can carry on testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are testing locally you can disable the SSL verification:

```
// Disable validation entirely
$client->request('GET', '/', ['verify' => false]);
```

See the docs for more information:
http://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request-options.html#verify-option

However you should not use this for anything else than testing, in normal cases you should use a certificate and verify this certificate properly.

Comment: Thanks that worked! i'll be sure to remove the header when uploading to production.. Quick question, do you know how Guzzle can return XML? I'm struggling to output the response - usually I get Json response but this time its xml.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If you get xml as response you can use something like: http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php to read it in php. However it's better to post as a new question.